# CoordinatorLayout, NestedScrollView and Overscroll

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I'm trying to create something I couldn't find anywhere... at least the way I want.

So here is the scenario I want to achieve:

I'm using the typical CoordinatorLayout with a AppBarLayout (ABL) and a NestedScrollView (NSV), so when I scroll in the NSV/ABL I get a nice parallax on the ABL.

The problem is that the NSV just occupy a small portion of the screen, at the bottom. If I scroll it up, it "detaches" from the bottom of the screen. Also, if I drag down the ABL too much, it stays too big.

What I wanted was to keep the NSV where it is, but allowing overscroll (restoring state after touch up).

Also, how to smooth scroll the NSV a specific amount? I tried playing with behavior.onNestedFling and behavior.onNestedPreScroll but the first uses speed, not a translation, and the second does not animate.

Can someone point me to the right direction in how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
João

**Edit: Here for some clarification:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oha7l.png

I've a CoordinatorLayout (red square), a AppBarLayout with an ImageView inside (green section) and a NestedScrollView (white section).

- The contents of the NestedScrollView have a small height (lets say it has small view inside).
- The AppBarLayout has a fixed size of "300dp".

Situation:

- If I scroll up either the appbarlayout or the nestedscrollview, the contents of the nestedscrollview scrolls up (thus collapsing the appbarlayout. I don't want this to happen if there's not enough content in the nestedscrollview. But I do want it to overscroll and return to original position after releasing press.
- If I scroll down, nothing happens (if appbarlayout has fixed height), and I also want it to overscroll and return to original position after releasing press.

Plus:

- When some event happens, I wanted to programmatically smooth scroll the appbarlayout a fixed amount of "dp" up or down. I tried using behavior.onNestedFling and behavior.onNestedPreScroll but those methods either don't scroll a fixed amount or don't animate the scroll.

Comment: Could you please do a small schema to represent the situation ? It's a bit difficult to understand well the situation

Comment: Edited the question, hope it helps :)

Comment: Now I understand it better. But as I can see you have a lot of requirements, and I'm afraid that using the coordinatorLayout won't solve all your problems. I think that you'll have to customize your layouts and your code to fit your requirements, I have some solutions in mind but right now I really need to sleep so I'll take a look tomorrow

Comment: Thanks David, waiting for your feedback!

Comment: What do you mean by ` not enough content in the nestedscrollview` exactly ?

Comment: Usually the nestedscrollview has some scrollable data inside, a big view, etc. Mine has just two textviews. Since i'm putting more views inside later, I used a nested scroll view.